# Android Button Background color not working

Tags: android, xml, button, background

I just started learning android and faced this issue. Watched a couple of tutorials but couldn't find the solution.
So basically I want to add a button inside a grid layout. And I want Button color to be white. So I added android:background="#ffffff" in button attributes. But its still showing the default color, i.e., blue.
Please help in changing the Button Color!!

Here is the xml code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#007b7e"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30sp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>



    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try use AppCompactButton instead of

```
<Button/>
```

use

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton />
```

that will do the trick

Comment: Can you please explain the reason. Yes it Worked!! But Why??

Comment: As you inflate your layout file, the AppCompat library switches some of your components to AppCompat versions (AppCompatButton, AppCompatTextView, etc). So, your AppCompatButton is still a subclass of Button, but it has some theming support built in.